# R set outliers in time series NA in series already containing NA

Tags: r, time-series, na, outliers

I have a time series containing NAs and some sudden jumps like this:

```
input=c(1:5, NA, 6:7,0,9:12)
```

In which 7,0,9 would be considered a jump for which 0 should be replaced by NA.

I would like to remove the very first value in which a sudden jump (with set value of what qualifies as a jump, in the example a change > 1) occurs and set it NA

the output for the example should look like this:

```
output=c(1:5,NA,6:7,NA,9:12)
```

I only want to set outliers NA, I do not want to overwrite the remaining values. 
The jump can be both negative and positive.

Problems I encountered:

1. The value after an existing NA value being counted as a jump
2. The "jump back" after the outlier being counted as jump

both of which resulted in more than necessary NAs, I try to keep as much original data as possible.

Any ideas? I have been stuck for a while. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the values always jump back to 1,2,3,4 pattern? Or can it also happen that e.g. 1,2,4,NA,7,8,9 occurs where 7,8,9 should be kept?

Comment: something like  1,2,4,NA,7,8,9  could happen for which 7,8,9 should be kept. real data has both small positive and negative changes (sensor noise) except for the jumps. NAs most often occur as single value, sometimes I have longer stretches of NA.

Comment: Even though your general problem is clear, perhaps you can post part of your real data. I can imagine there may be many exceptions and special cases.

Comment: real data looks like this: 
`sensor=c(20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.1,20.2,20.2,20.1,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,17.7,18.9,19.3,19.4,19.4,19.4,19.5,19.5,19.5)`
In which the "17.7" entry should be NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three situations that are very similar but require different degrees of difficulties in terms of exceptions:

## Situation 1

If the pattern always jumps back to 1-increase with a couple of interruptions, I would create `vector_check` which resembles the perfect vector. Everything in `input` that deviates from this should be set to `NA`:

```
vector_check <- min(input):max(input)
inds         <- vector_check != input
input[inds]  <- NA
```

## Situation 2

If the pattern is less predictable and you basically wish to look for 'irregular' pattern, you'll get a more complicated situation. A possible solution would be to create a `while`-loop that checks which increments are larger than 2 (or whatever value seems sensible) and then replaces the problematic location `bump_inds` with an `NA`. Here I assume that an outlier creates two large increments: one because the value suddenly drops (increases) and one because it rises back up (drops back down) to its old value. This process proceeds until no problematic locations remain:

```
bump_ind <- rep(0, 3)

while(length(bump_ind) > 1){
  bump_ind        <- which( abs(diff(input)) > 2 )
  input[bump_ind[2]] <- NA
}

input
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA  6  7 NA  9 10 11 12
```

## Situation3

A third option, based on your real data `sensor` shows that the data does not have to jump back to a the previous level:

```
input    <- c(20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.1,20.2,20.2,20.1,20.2, 20.2,20.2,20.2,17.7,
              18.9,19.3,19.4,19.4,19.4,19.5,19.5,19.5)
bump_ind <- rep(0, 3)

while(length(bump_ind) > 1){
  bump_ind        <- which( abs(diff(input)) > 2 )
  if(length(bump_ind) > 2){
    bump_ind <- bump_ind[1:2]
  }
  if( length(bump_ind) == 1 ){
      input[bump_ind[1] + 1] <- NA
  } else if( diff(bump_ind > 1) ){
      input[bump_ind[1] + 1] <- NA
  } else{
      input[bump_ind[2]] <- NA
  }
}

input
# [1] 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.1 20.2 20.2 20.1 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2   NA 18.9 19.3
# [16] 19.4 19.4 19.4 19.5 19.5 19.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a more robust solution since you could modify the linear model of your data below if necessary:

Your data:

```
 input <- c(1:5, NA, 6:7,0,9:12)
```

A sequence of numbers:

```
x <- seq_len(length(input))
```

Select some threshold value for the residual of a linear model:

```
threshhold = 2
```

Calculate the linear model of your data and the residuals and select the outliers:

```
select <- abs((predict(lm(input ~ x), newdata = data.frame(x = x)) -input)) >= threshhold
```

Replace the outliers with 'NA'

```
input[select] <- NA
input
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA  6  7 NA  9 10 11 12
```

EDIT:
With your data:

```
input=c(20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2,
        20.1, 20.2, 20.2, 20.1,
        20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2,
        17.7, 18.9, 19.3, 19.4,
        19.4, 19.4, 19.5, 19.5,
        19.5)

x <- seq_len(length(input))
threshhold = 0.7
select <- abs((predict(lm(input ~ x), newdata = data.frame(x = x)) - input)) >= threshhold

inputnew <- input
inputnew[select] <- NA

input
 [1] 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.1 20.2 20.2 20.1 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 17.7 18.9 19.3
 [16] 19.4 19.4 19.4 19.5 19.5 19.5

inputnew
 [1] 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.1 20.2 20.2 20.1 20.2 20.2 20.2 20.2   NA 18.9 19.3
 [16] 19.4 19.4 19.4 19.5 19.5 19.5
```